# jquery ui -how to submit ajax dialog?

Tags: ajax, node.js, jquery-ui

i don't understand my code..i am using jquery ui dialog for now,i using server node.js. i get the data from db. I am currently using the Detail view making the dialog. view page output is well with db data but click the submit does not do any work why?

my error message:TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

my code.

```
    $("#detail-form").dialog({

    autoOpen : false,
    height : 600,
    width : 600,
    modal : true,
    buttons:{
        submit:function(data){
            $.ajax({
                url:'/edit',
                dataType:'json',
                type:'POST',
                data: $("#detail-form").serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                    alert('성공');
                    alert('data');
                    //location.href='/';
                },
                error:function(request,status,error){
                    alert("code:"+request.status+"\n"+"message:"+request.responseText+"\n"+"error:"+error);
                 }
            });
        }
    }

});
$.ajax({
     url: '/detail/' + id,
     dataType : 'json',
     type: 'GET',
     success:function(data) {
        alert(data);
         $.each(data, function(i, item){
            $("#detail-form").empty();
            var css = $("<link type=\"text/css\" href=\"/main.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />" +
                    "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/jquery-ui.css\" />");

            var row = $("<form id=\"form\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" action=\"/edit\"><fieldset><legend>view detail</legend><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"file_no\" value=" + item.file_no+ "><table id=\"board_write\" width=500 height=500><colgroup><col style=\"width: 250px\" /><col style=\"width: 710px\" /></colgroup><tbody>"+
                    "<tr><th class=\"lside\">No.</th><td class=\"rside\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"simple-input\" value="+ item.file_no+ " disabled>" + 
                    "</td></tr><p><tr><th class=\"lside\">filename</th><td class=\"rside\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"simple-input\" value="+item.file_name+">" + 
                    "</td></tr><tr><th class=\"lside\">filemodel</th><td class=\"rside\"><a href=\"/download/item.file_model\" class=\"simple-input\">" + item.file_model + 
                    "</td><tr><tr><th class=\"lside\">file</th><td class=\"rside\"><input type=\"file\" name=\"file_model\" id=\"series\" value="+ item.file_model +">" +
                    "</td></tr><tr><th class=\"lside\">filecontent</th><td class=\"rside\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"simple-input\" value="+ item.file_content+"></td></tr></tbody></table>");
            var btn = $("<button id=\"edit\" name=\"save\">Edit</button></fieldset></form>");


            $("#detail-form").append(css);

            $("#detail-form").append(row);
            $("#detail-form").append(btn);
        }); 
        $("#detail-form").dialog("open"); 

     },
         error:function(request,status,error){
        alert("code:"+request.status+"\n"+"message:"+request.responseText+"\n"+"error:"+error);
     }
}); 
  }
```

Comment: Are you that `#detail-form` exists when this code is being run, or is it only added in the AJAX call?

Comment: @Scimonster this code when i click submit in dialog,'TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined' printed..btn is not workin so i added submit buttons in dialog